# Stable homotopy group of K(1)-local spectra

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, higher-algebra, ring-spectra

Fix a prime $p$. We let $C$ be the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and let $\mathcal{O}_C$ be its ring of integers. For a $p$-complete $K(\mathcal{O}_C;\mathbb{Z}_p)$-module $M$, there is the unit map
$$
M \to L_{K(1)}M.
$$
If $M$ is the p-completion of the algebraic K theory of a smooth projective variety $M$ over $C$, by Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture, the unit map
$$
K^{alg}(X)_{\hat{p}} \to L_{K(1)}K^{alg}(X)
$$
is $n$-connected for some natural number $n$.
Can we extend this story to general $M$? That is, the unit map
$
M \to L_{K(1)}M
$
is $n$-connected for some natural number $n$?

Comment: What are “hotopogy groups?”

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: There is still a typo in the title, and at least two more in the body of the question.  Please proof-read it.